# Find hive external table name from HDFS directory

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql

Is it possible to get the external table name if the only information I have is the HDFS directory.
For example, I create the table with

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS userinfo(id String, name String)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/testuser/log/2019-02-18/‘
```

To get the location from table name, I can use

```
show create table userinfo;
```

But if I want to get the table name from "hdfs:///user/testuser/log/2019-02-18/"?
Is it possible to find the table name "userinfo" from the directory?

Thanks
David